# SharePoint 2010 In-Browser Form User Info Changing after Submit

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010, infopath-forms-services

I have a In-Browser Form I published to SharePoint 2010 via Infopath and have a section in the beginning which pulls the current user data to get their Name, Email, Number, etc. The issue is once a user submits the form and I take a look with the In-Browser feature in SharePoint, the information changes to my info instead of the submitter. However, when I open in the form via Infopath application, it shows the originial submitters info. Is there a way or an option I'm not aware of which will fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. On the text boxes that pulls the user info, go to the Text Box Properties and under Default Value, deselect the checkbox "Refresh value when formula is recalculated".